# How to publish custom build of ckeditor classic build on npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ckeditor, ckeditor5

i want to use `MathType` pluggin in `ckeditor5 classic build` so according to documentation, i have to create custom build so to do that i  have created a custom build of `ckeditor5 classic build` to use `MathType` plugin. i followed [this](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installing-plugins.html) instruction. i forked `ckeditor5 classic build` repo , clone it, added `MathType` pluggin and created build.  Now i want to publish this custom build so that i can use it in my project. so when i run `npm publish --access public` i got following errors

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@username%2fckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-28T13_11_47_673Z-debug.log
```

log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'publish',
1 verbose cli   '--access',
1 verbose cli   'public'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose npm-session 6e8acbd8d8a13287
5 verbose publish [ '.' ]
6 info lifecycle @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0~prepublish: @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
7 info lifecycle @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0~prepare: @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
8 info lifecycle @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0~prepublishOnly: @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
9 info lifecycle @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0~prepack: @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
10 info lifecycle @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0~postpack: @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
11 notice
12 notice package: @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
13 notice === Tarball Contents ===
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/af.js
14 notice 2.3kB   build/translations/ar.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/ast.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/az.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/bg.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/ca.js
14 notice 791.8kB build/ckeditor.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/cs.js
14 notice 2.0kB   build/translations/da.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/de-ch.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/de.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/el.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/en-au.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/en-gb.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/eo.js
14 notice 2.3kB   build/translations/es.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/et.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/eu.js
14 notice 2.9kB   build/translations/fa.js
14 notice 2.0kB   build/translations/fi.js
14 notice 2.3kB   build/translations/fr.js
14 notice 2.3kB   build/translations/gl.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/gu.js
14 notice 2.3kB   build/translations/he.js
14 notice 2.0kB   build/translations/hr.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/hu.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/id.js
14 notice 2.4kB   build/translations/it.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/ja.js
14 notice 2.6kB   build/translations/km.js
14 notice 2.5kB   build/translations/kn.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/ko.js
14 notice 3.3kB   build/translations/ku.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/lt.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/lv.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/ms.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/nb.js
14 notice 4.7kB   build/translations/ne.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/nl.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/no.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/oc.js
14 notice 2.3kB   build/translations/pl.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/pt-br.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/pt.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/ro.js
14 notice 3.4kB   build/translations/ru.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/si.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/sk.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/sl.js
14 notice 2.0kB   build/translations/sq.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/sr-latn.js
14 notice 3.1kB   build/translations/sr.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/sv.js
14 notice 2.9kB   build/translations/th.js
14 notice 2.1kB   build/translations/tr.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/tt.js
14 notice 2.2kB   build/translations/ug.js
14 notice 3.7kB   build/translations/uk.js
14 notice 2.4kB   build/translations/vi.js
14 notice 1.9kB   build/translations/zh-cn.js
14 notice 1.8kB   build/translations/zh.js
14 notice 3.3kB   package.json
14 notice 4.6MB   build/ckeditor.js.map
14 notice 124.9kB CHANGELOG.md
14 notice 1.3kB   LICENSE.md
14 notice 3.4kB   README.md
15 notice === Tarball Details ===
16 notice name:          @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin
16 notice version:       18.0.0
16 notice package size:  1.3 MB
16 notice unpacked size: 5.7 MB
16 notice shasum:        66d56f77be66314eabdcc855622b75ddb65cd095
16 notice integrity:     sha512-RgbLfmEWflwxk[...]Ay3CN/wGUk69g==
16 notice total files:   66
17 notice
18 http fetch PUT 403 https://registry.npmjs.org/@username%2fckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin 19846ms
19 verbose stack Error: 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@username%2fckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin - Forbidden
19 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
19 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
20 verbose statusCode 403
21 verbose pkgid @username/ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin@18.0.0
22 verbose cwd C:\Users\Bilal\Documents\ckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype
23 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
24 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish" "--access" "public"
25 verbose node v12.16.1
26 verbose npm  v6.13.4
27 error code E403
28 error 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/@username%2fckeditor5-build-classic-with-mathtype-plugin - Forbidden
29 error 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
29 error 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
30 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What i am doing wrong?  i am logged in on npm using CLI too,